# Best Way To Handle SQL Numerous Joins For Lookup

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm wondering if there is a better way to handle all these joins? I need to lookup the contact name from the ViewContactsLookup table numerous times. Is there a way that so many joins aren't needed?

```
SELECT        ISNULL(dbo.NCR.Id, '') AS Id, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.NCR, '') AS Ncr, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.AcctgDate, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AS AcctgDate, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CorrectActDate, CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                         '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AS CorrectActDate, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.AssignedToMORDate, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AS AssignedToMorDate, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CloseoutDate, CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                         '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AS CloseoutDate, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CustomerContactYN, '') AS CustomerContactYN, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.ReportedDate, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AS ReportedDate, 
                         ISNULL(dbo.NCR.NonConformityComments, '') AS NonConformityComments, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.ProbableCauseComments, '') AS ProbableCauseComments, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CorrectiveActionComments, '') 
                         AS CorrectiveActionComments, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.Comments, N'') AS Comments, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.InvestigatorId, '') AS InvestigatorId, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.MORId, '') AS MorId, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CategoryId, '') AS CategoryId, 
                         ISNULL(dbo.NCR.PropertyId, '') AS PropertyId, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CustomerId, '') AS CustomerId, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.LinkedInfo, '') AS LinkedInfo, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CreatedById, '') AS CreatedById, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CreatedDate, 
                         CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AS CreatedDate, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.LastModifiedById, '') AS LastModifiedById, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.LastModifiedDate, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) 
                         AS LastModifiedDate, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.OwnerId, '') AS OwnerId, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.InvestDate, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AS InvestDate, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CloseoutYN, '') AS CloseoutYN, 
                         ISNULL(dbo.NCR.ImplementedYN, '') AS ImplementedYN, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.EffectiveYN, '') AS EffectiveYN, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.ActiveYN, '') AS ActiveYN, CASE WHEN ISNULL(LastModifiedDate, '1/1/1900') 
                         <> '1/1/1900' THEN LastModifiedDate ELSE isnull(CreatedDate, '1/1/1900') END AS LastActivityDate, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.AccountId, '') AS AccountId, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CategoryTxt, '') AS CategoryTxt, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.PropertyTxt, 
                         '') AS PropertyTxt, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.PreventativeActionComments, '') AS PreventativeActionComments, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.AcctgOutlookIds, '') AS AcctgOutlookIds, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CorrectActOutlookIds, '') AS CorrectActOutlookIds, 
                         ISNULL(dbo.NCR.InvestOutlookIds, '') AS InvestOutlookIds, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.AssignedToMOROutlookIds, '') AS AssignedToMorOutlookIds, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CategoryICP1Txt, '') AS CategoryIcp1Txt, 
                         ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CategoryICP2Txt, '') AS CategoryIcp2Txt, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CorrectActMtgTxt, '') AS CorrectActMtgTxt, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.ProductsTxt, '') AS ProductsTxt, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CorrectActId, '') AS CorrectActId, 
                         ISNULL(dbo.NCR.AssignedToMORId, '') AS AssignedToMorId, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.AccountingComments, '') AS AccountingComments, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.AccountingContactId, '') AS AccountingContactId, 
                         ISNULL(dbo.NCR.AssignedToAccountingId, '') AS AssignedToAccountingId, 
                         CASE WHEN CorrectiveActionComments > '' THEN '<i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-fw" style="color:green"></i> Completed' ELSE '<i class="fa fa-square-o fa-fw"></i> Incomplete' END AS zzm, 
                         CASE WHEN AccountingComments > '' THEN '<i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-fw" style="color:green"></i> Completed' ELSE '<i class="fa fa-square-o fa-fw"></i> Incomplete' END AS zza, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.LotNum, '') 
                         AS LotNum, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.ComplaintDescription, '') AS ComplaintDescription, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.PackageConditionTxt, '') AS PackageConditionTxt, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.MaterialDisposalTxt, '') AS MaterialDisposalTxt, 
                         ISNULL(dbo.NCR.MaterialTransferTxt, '') AS MaterialTransferTxt, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.ReturnInspectedById, '') AS ReturnInspectedById, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.ReturnInspectionDate, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) 
                         AS ReturnInspectionDate, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.ReturnStatusTxt, '') AS ReturnStatusTxt, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.ReturnNewLotNum, '') AS ReturnNewLotNum, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.RGA, '') AS RGA, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.QcStatusTxt, '') 
                         AS QcStatusTxt, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.QcConformingTxt, '') AS QcConformingTxt, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.QcNonconformingTxt, '') AS QcNonconformingTxt, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.QcSupervisorId, '') AS QcSupervisorId, 
                         ISNULL(dbo.NCR.QcSupervisorDate, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AS QcSupervisorDate, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CreditStatusTxt, '') AS CreditStatusTxt, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CreditDate, CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                         '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AS CreditDate, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CreditRespondDate, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AS CreditRespondDate, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CreditAmountDec, '0') AS CreditAmountDec, 
                         ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CreditCommentsTxt, '') AS CreditCommentsTxt, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.CreditById, '') AS CreditById, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.ApprovalSentDate, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AS ApprovalSentDate, 
                         ISNULL(dbo.NCR.OperationsApprovedDate, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AS OperationsApprovedDate, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.OperationsApprovedById, '') AS OperationsApprovedById, 
                         ISNULL(dbo.NCR.OperationsApprovedCommentsTxt, '') AS OperationsApprovedCommentsTxt, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.SalesApprovedDate, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) AS SalesApprovedDate, 
                         ISNULL(dbo.NCR.SalesApprovedCommentsTxt, '') AS SalesApprovedCommentsTxt, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.SalesApprovedById, '') AS SalesApprovedById, ISNULL(dbo.NCR.NCRStep, '') AS NCRStep, 
                         ISNULL(ViewContactsLookup_2.FullName, '') AS CorrectActByTxt, ISNULL(ViewContactsLookup_1.FullName, '') AS AssignedToMORByTxt, ISNULL(ViewContactsLookup_3.FullName, '') AS AssignedToAccountingByTxt, 
                         ISNULL(ViewContactsLookup_4.FullName, '') AS AccountingContactTxt, ISNULL(ViewContactsLookup_5.FullName, '') AS InvestigatorTxt, ISNULL(ViewContactsLookup_6.FullName, '') AS MorTxt, 
                         ISNULL(dbo.ViewAccountsLookup.Name, '') AS AccountTxt, ISNULL(ViewContactsLookup_8.FullName, '') AS CreatedByTxt, ISNULL(ViewContactsLookup_7.FullName, '') AS LastModifiedByTxt, 
                         ISNULL(ViewContactsLookup_9.FullName, '') AS OwnerTxt, ISNULL(ViewContactsLookup_10.FullName, '') AS ReturnInspectedByTxt, ISNULL(ViewContactsLookup_11.FullName, '') AS QcSupervisorTxt, 
                         ISNULL(dbo.ViewContactsLookup.FullName, '') AS CreditByTxt, ISNULL(ViewContactsLookup_12.FullName, '') AS OperationsApprovedByTxt, ISNULL(ViewContactsLookup_13.FullName, '') AS SalesApprovedByTxt, 
                         ISNULL(ViewContactsLookup_9.FullName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(ViewContactsLookup_4.FullName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(ViewContactsLookup_6.FullName, '') AS AssignedToTxt
FROM            dbo.NCR LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.ViewContactsLookup ON dbo.NCR.CreditById = dbo.ViewContactsLookup.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS ViewContactsLookup_13 ON dbo.NCR.SalesApprovedById = ViewContactsLookup_13.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS ViewContactsLookup_12 ON dbo.NCR.OperationsApprovedById = ViewContactsLookup_12.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS ViewContactsLookup_11 ON dbo.NCR.QcSupervisorId = ViewContactsLookup_11.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS ViewContactsLookup_10 ON dbo.NCR.ReturnInspectedById = ViewContactsLookup_10.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS ViewContactsLookup_9 ON dbo.NCR.OwnerId = ViewContactsLookup_9.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS ViewContactsLookup_7 ON dbo.NCR.LastModifiedById = ViewContactsLookup_7.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS ViewContactsLookup_8 ON dbo.NCR.CreatedById = ViewContactsLookup_8.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.ViewAccountsLookup ON dbo.NCR.AccountId = dbo.ViewAccountsLookup.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS ViewContactsLookup_6 ON dbo.NCR.MORId = ViewContactsLookup_6.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS ViewContactsLookup_5 ON dbo.NCR.InvestigatorId = ViewContactsLookup_5.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS ViewContactsLookup_4 ON dbo.NCR.AccountingContactId = ViewContactsLookup_4.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS ViewContactsLookup_3 ON dbo.NCR.AssignedToAccountingId = ViewContactsLookup_3.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS ViewContactsLookup_1 ON dbo.NCR.AssignedToMORId = ViewContactsLookup_1.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS ViewContactsLookup_2 ON dbo.NCR.CorrectActId = ViewContactsLookup_2.Id
```

Comment: Nope. Each of those joins is to a different column in the NCR. The only real issue I see in your posted query is that it is a wall of text. Moving each column to a new line in the query makes this a lot easier on the eyes and easier to maintain. I would probably use a better alias than numbering them. They all have a specific purpose so making the alias relevant makes it a lot easier to understand the query. Otherwise you have to constantly refer to the alias list to know what ViewContactsLookup_5 is the investigator.

Comment: Answered by @SeaLange  added below so that it may get accepted. Hope that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Each of those joins is to a different column in the NCR. The only real issue I see in your posted query is that it is a wall of text. Moving each column to a new line in the query makes this a lot easier on the eyes and easier to maintain. I would probably use a better alias than numbering them. They all have a specific purpose so making the alias relevant makes it a lot easier to understand the query. Otherwise you have to constantly refer to the alias list to know what ViewContactsLookup_5 is the investigator. – Sean Lange

e.g:

```
SELECT
      dbo.NCR.id
      , ISNULL(correctact.FullName, '') AS correctactbytxt
      , ISNULL(assignedtomor.FullName, '') AS assignedtomorbytxt
      , ISNULL(assignedtoaccounting.FullName, '') AS assignedtoaccountingbytxt
      , ISNULL(accountingcontact.FullName, '') AS accountingcontacttxt
      , ISNULL(investigator.FullName, '') AS investigatortxt
      , ISNULL(mor.FullName, '') AS mortxt
      , ISNULL(creditby.Name, '') AS accounttxt
      , ISNULL(createdby.FullName, '') AS createdbytxt
      , ISNULL(lastmodifiedby.FullName, '') AS lastmodifiedbytxt
      , ISNULL(owner.FullName, '') AS ownertxt
      , ISNULL(returninspectedby.FullName, '') AS returninspectedbytxt
      , ISNULL(qcsupervisor.FullName, '') AS qcsupervisortxt
      , ISNULL(dbo.ViewContactsLookup.FullName, '') AS creditbytxt
      , ISNULL(operationsapproved.FullName, '') AS operationsapprovedbytxt
      , ISNULL(salesapprovedby.FullName, '') AS salesapprovedbytxt
      , ISNULL(owner.FullName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(accountingcontact.FullName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(mor.FullName, '') AS assignedtotxt
FROM dbo.NCR
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewAccountsLookup ON dbo.NCR.AccountId = dbo.ViewAccountsLookup.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS AccountingContact ON dbo.NCR.AccountingContactId = AccountingContact.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS AssignedToAccounting ON dbo.NCR.AssignedToAccountingId = AssignedToAccounting.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS AssignedToMOR ON dbo.NCR.AssignedToMORId = AssignedToMOR.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS CorrectAct ON dbo.NCR.CorrectActId = CorrectAct.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS CreatedBy ON dbo.NCR.CreatedById = CreatedBy.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS CreditBy ON dbo.NCR.CreditById = CreditBy.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS Investigator ON dbo.NCR.InvestigatorId = Investigator.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS LastModifiedBy ON dbo.NCR.LastModifiedById = LastModifiedBy.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS MOR ON dbo.NCR.MORId = MOR.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS OperationsApproved ON dbo.NCR.OperationsApprovedById = OperationsApproved.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS Owner ON dbo.NCR.OwnerId = Owner.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS QcSupervisor ON dbo.NCR.QcSupervisorId = QcSupervisor.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS ReturnInspectedBy ON dbo.NCR.ReturnInspectedById = ReturnInspectedBy.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ViewContactsLookup AS SalesApprovedBy ON dbo.NCR.SalesApprovedById = SalesApprovedBy.Id
;
```